# How can we develop a proxy for HDFS ( Hadoop Distributed File System)

Tags: hadoop, proxy, hdfs, protocol-buffers, webhdfs

I am working on a research project whereby I need to create some sort of proxy for HDFS such that we can trap the call to HDFS and apply some access/deny ( of files) policy before returning it back to users. For interfaces for HDFS like HttpFs and WebHDFS, it is easy to design proxy systems as they use HTTP for communication with the client. But HDFS driver uses Protocols defined using protocol buffers to communicate between client and namenode. Is there any hook within HDFS code to design a proxy around HDFS native protocols. The Hadoop version for this is 2.6.

Answer (score 3):

Apache Knox may or may not be what you are looking for. Arnon's answer above doesn't have the correct url though. Please see: http://knox.apache.org/

We do not have file level ACLs built in to the provided authorization provider but you can create a custom provider and plug that in.

Keep in mind that Knox is a proxy for WebHDFS access and does not come into play for accessing files directly through HDFS.

Therefore any authorization checks that are done at the gateway will not be done when accessing the same files directly. This is why we generally do service level authorization checks at the gateway and leave fine grained authorization checks to be done at the resource itself.

Hope this is useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

external (perimeter) security like you mention for WebHDFS is one thing. You can extend that for submitting jobs etc. (in fact it has already been done see [apache knox](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/tree/trunk/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs))

The other this is not a proxy but rather an alternate implementation of [FileSystem](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html) class. Is has also been implemented several times - 
You can see more information [here](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HCFS)